# MS Office Security Warning enable content is not saved for files on network drive

Tags: networking, vpn, microsoft-office

I have a shared folder that I access via VPN which I  mapped to my X: drive.
All Microsoft office files in this folder appear with the Security Message "Enable Content" when I open them. This is normal, in so far as this is the security setting in MS Office, however, **the documents do not remain trusted!**

I have attempted the following:

- To add the shared drive in the File>Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>Trusted Locations. MS will not let me add the shared drive! The error message says:

> The path you have entered cannot be used as a Trusted Location for
> security reasons. Choose another location or a specific folder.

- In the same place, under Protected View, I unchecked the option "Enable Protected View for files located in potentially unsafe locations". This also did nothing.

The only thing that makes a difference, is if I enable all macros, an option that I do not want! I want to first be asked. But only once.

**Does anyone know how to add mapped network drives that are linked via VPN as a Trusted Location?**

Comment: "will not let me add the shared drive!" - Is this because the interface is grayed out? This means your Administrator is managing the trusted locations. Please [edit] your question to provide an adequate amount of information with the reason you cannot add a shared drive to the trusted location.

Comment: I updated the question with the specific error message. It doesn't really give much info... at least to my mind. They don't specify which security settings.

Comment: Are you using a UNC path to the network location?

Comment: No, the folder I mapped it to: X:\ drive

Comment: I have already added the server address... but I'm not sure that is the UNC. Server Address looks like this: \\sgmef001\*\  I accepts this version as a location, but in the end, i still need to enable the documents again and again

Comment: I just used a function to derive the UNC: \\10.115.XXX.XXX\Collaborations\_Datenbank\ Attempting to add this to the Trusted Folders returns the same error message that I gave in my original post.

Comment: [Try a device name instead of an ip address](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9ac965b6-0bbf-433e-9ffd-933a7254bf27/quotpath-cannot-be-used-as-a-trusted-location-for-security-reasonsquot?forum=word)

Comment: I am at loss how to get the device name, as it is a server that I don't own.

Comment: I have also found this article which provided a solution... sadly didn't work for me: https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=140594

Comment: You assign it yourself by editing your hosts file.  The discussion I linked to indicated that.  So have you tried doing that?